# ListIterator throwing an error

Tags: java

```
private List<RolePermission> permissionList = new ArrayList<RolePermission>();
ListIterator<RolePermission> iterator = permissionList.listIterator();
permissionList.remove(iterator.next().getRolePermissionName().contains("http"));
```

I want to remove those item from list which is containing term "http" . but this code is not working.

Comment: "this code is not working" is quite vague: Does it compile? Does it throw an exception? What exception? On what line? etc.

Comment: You should use Iterator.remove() to do this.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection

Answer (score 5):

You need to use iterator.remove();

```
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
   if (iterator.next().getRolePermissionName().contains("http"))
       iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: You should "accept" the answer if you think @Matthew gave what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The method [List#remove(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) is in your case not suitable for the type `boolean` (autoboxed to `Boolean`), the type which `contains()` returns. A `ClassCastException` is thrown.

you could try this to remove using iterator:

```
private List<RolePermission> permissionList = new ArrayList<RolePermission>();   
ListIterator<RolePermission> iterator = permissionList.listIterator();
RolePermission rp = iterator.next();
if(rp.getRolePermissionName().contains("http")) {
    iterator.remove();
}
```